Get HTTPS Method using VB6
I have been using the following procedure to read data from webpages on HTTP for years.
    Dim strReturn                   ' As String
    Dim objHTTP                     ' As MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
    Dim strURL 
    If Len(strURL) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    strURL = "https://www.codebankers.com/secure1.html"
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send                    'Get it.
    strReturn = objHTTP.responseText
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    GetHTMLCode = strReturn

But since my Hosting company have forced HTTPS on all domains, the procedure no longer works and give me an error of "An error occurred in the secure channel support"
Please i need help on a procedure that can work for HTTPS.
I really want to be able to read from HTTPS web pages, just as this works for HTTP.
